# Migrated wordpress site give "Undefined variable: php" warnings

Tags: wp-admin, migration

I have just migrated my wordpress site from my laptop to my desktop. I get server error 500 when I try /localhost/wordpress/wp-admin. So I turned on WP_DEBUG and now I get a series of

```
Notice: Undefined variable: skype_mu_dir in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/skype-online-status/skype-status.php on line 42 
Notice: Undefined variable: skype_mu_dir in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/skype-online-status/skype-status.php on line 43 
Notice: Undefined variable: user in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium/symposium_hooks_filters.php on line 553 
Notice: Undefined variable: user in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium/symposium_hooks_filters.php on line 555 
Notice: Undefined variable: uid in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium/symposium_hooks_filters.php on line 600 
Notice: Undefined variable: uid in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-symposium/symposium_hooks_filters.php on line 602 
Notice: Undefined variable: cache_needs_updating in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/s2member/includes/classes/cache.inc.php on line 97 
Notice: Undefined index: level-1_label in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/s2member/includes/classes/constants.inc.php on line 287 
Notice: Undefined index: contact_me_data in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/contactme/contactmedotcom.php on line 34 
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/flexicache/FlexiCache/Store/Memcache.php on line 63
```

A ls -l on /var/www shows

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data 4096 2012-06-13 21:35 wordpress
```

A ls -l on /var/www/wordpress shows

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 www-data www-data  4096 2012-06-13 19:24 wp-admin
```

A ps -ef | grep apache2 reports

```
prompt:/var/www/wordpress$ sudo ps -ef | grep apache2
root     14040     1  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14043 14040  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14044 14040  0 19:23 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14045 14040  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14046 14040  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14047 14040  0 19:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14048 14040  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 14056 14040  0 19:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I wonder what I am missing. I am sure its something really small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notices won't trigger a server 500 error.  However, "fatal errors" will.  From your logs above:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/flexicache/FlexiCache/Store/Memcache.php on line 63
```

This means you're running a plugin that depends on Memcache and your local system doesn't have Memcache support.  Disable or remove the FlexiCache plugin, or install Memcache.

---

One other important thing to remember is that simply installing Memcache on your server isn't usually enough.  PHP has to be compiled with support for it, or you need to [manually load the PHP's Memcache extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php).  It's not bundled with PHP by default, though some hosts might install it for you.

Comment: I have installed memcached and loaded it too. Still same issue.

Comment: I forgot to install php5-memcached on ubuntu. Works now. Thanks.

Comment: See my edit. Remember, PHP's Memcache extension isn't bundled by default, so installing it is *part* of installing/configuring Memcache.